# Trying to compare strings in 2d array ascending order of ascii values

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I need to input strings form the user and arrange them in ascending order of ascii values. Can anyone help me where I am wrong? I am geting errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int sort(char[10][10]);

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i,j,length,fun;
  char c;
  char a[10][10];
  printf("Please enter ten strings : \n");
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  { 
    j=-1;   
    while(a[i][j]!='\n'&&j<10)
    {   
      scanf("%c",&a[i][++j]);
    }
    a[i][j]='\0';
  }

  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    printf("\n");   
    for(j=0;j<10,a[i][j]!='\0';j++)
    {
      printf("a[%d][%d]=%c\n",i,j,a[i][j]);
    }
  }
  fun=sort(a[10][10]);
  return 0;
}

int sort(char s[10][10])
{
  int i,j;
  char temp[10];
  for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) { 
    for (j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
      if (strcmp(s[j - 1], s[j]) > 0) 
      {
        strcpy(temp, s[j - 1]);
        strcpy(s[j - 1], s[j]);
        strcpy(s[j], temp);
      }
    }
  }
  printf("Sorted list(in ascending order is:"); 
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)   
  {     
    for(j=0;j<10,s[i][j]!='\0';j++)
    {
      printf("%c\n",s[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return 0;    
}
```

Comment: "*I am geting errors*" -- **What** are the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems:

1. This:

   ```
   j=-1;
   ```

   should be

   ```
   j = 0;
   ```

   because array indices start from zero, not -1.
2. This:

   ```
   while(a[i][j]!='\n'&&j<10)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   while(a[i][j] != '\n' && j < 9)
   ```

   so that the NUL-terminator is not written into an invalid memory location if the user enters more than 9 characters.
3. This:

   ```
   fun=sort(a[10][10]);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   fun = sort(a);
   ```

   because you want to send the array to the function.